# Array of property names into properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've got an object where each key is a function that could be used by a "processor".

```
const fns = {
  foo: () => ({ some: "data", for: "foo" }),
  bar: () => ({ and: "data", for: "bar" }),
  baz: () => ({ baz: "also", is: "here" }),
};
```

Then I've got an interface describing the specification of a "processor":

```
interface NeedyProcessor {
  needed: Array<keyof typeof fns>;
  // Question 1: Can needsMet be typed more strongly?
  process: (needsMet: any) => any;
}
```

My goal is that `needed` should be an array with the function properties in fns that this processor needs to process.

So if `needed` is `["foo"]` it means that `processor` will get an object `needsMet` that has a single property, `foo` with the value of `foo` from `fns`.

I didn't know how to type this properly, and the lack of typing makes this error go under the radar of Typescript:

```
const broken: NeedyProcessor = {
  needed: ["foo", "baz"],
  process: (needsMet) => ({
    fooResult: needsMet.foo(),
    // Question 1 cont: So that this call would give an error in the IDE
    barResult: needsMet.bar(), // Runtime error! bar won't exist
    bazResult: needsMet.baz(),
  }),
};
```

Just for completion and perhaps to clarify a bit more here is also an example without a runtime error:

```
const working: NeedyProcessor = {
  needed: ["bar"],
  process: (needsMet) => ({
    barResult: needsMet.bar(),
  }),
};
```

I will have a function similar to this one for making the call. It's important to only pass in the needed `fns` to `process`:

```
function callProcessor(spec: NeedyProcessor) {
  // Question 2: Could this any be typed more strongly? Not as important as question 1 though
  const needsMet: any = {}

  spec.needed.forEach(x => needsMet[x] = fns[x])

  return spec.process(needsMet);
}
```

One will work and not the other:

```
console.log("working", callProcessor(working));
console.log("broken", callProcessor(broken));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZpGBeGBvAsAKBvEIBcMAFAJTIB8xqMEIAtgKaEBEAJgIZTvMA0uATizh5mMAL4keWHACN2g4mSSUi1dmFYsOXXgJZz%20oiVOww5AL0KkKVM%200sxm7ADa1dASwgsAFg34MjSSwxAG4sLHcwKD84dmAGGAA5BgZWAE8ABX4QeIhafjRpGDAU1lTCAEF%20fnY0gB4AawY0kDgYKDSABwZW%20EhyMNMAeiGYAEUAVwZod3AYAEZCAGF1YtKIAFkGWBkEju7WGDoQfxoobLAAc2c0gH4izuzcr2IS1M3twnU0pUpvwbE4UwoEgO2yTTAhGSqUyT2m%20WQhVMbzKmhgAG1mMIQLpmBZmABdEw4R45eFWFEfKC-KhFHDYgBK0wmzighEpWygADpsaRiTgYCNxlMZnN5jAQWyYABlEDtbyceWeCUuZwwADuIBZh0u7gAbglVn5sgVIvKEgBJAAiAFE6XZ%20EyICypRztlyDHzBaMGRMou5GDBjScAIQOjXgADksAYAA9PFB7RYnS72etOR77HyisZgoMsCDoBH%20A1IpcoaVYWS8idERhkaVyhi8fJCfzSc8KentjTVEn5CnWWn3hnPUFTLnMKEgXA-cAoLMwCrnM4stX8kQIN1gBWYWvnicyPWcELJtMF3MAEzLLXOQ5QbzK75mPZdVJHE4JaAXa53JIgWB2AgGAA06E4uCiGAgJgABHEULyXcUHy1S5vCKQtYDdKVnxQVBAUwIotwYYAuRRVIeROG04m8IhYxsLD0VjAlEQQCBGIJEggRwfwoAmfglyIkiO3hIgsJIAEgULEBnAYLlnBAS4iGYTUSzLXRgFVfd4ROIgVNLK4SHEyTwFoGS5IUpSZHBBgwHUzS4RrfgiCskAIUMwYgA)

Comment: You're going to need generics; there's no good specific type that works (theoretically one could make `NeedyProcessor` a union of all possible subsets of `keyof typeof fns` but that scales poorly and you don't get the inference you want anyway).  To make inference work for you, you'd have a helper function to initialize variables of type `NeedyProcessor<K>`.  And then `callProcessor()` also becomes generic.  The code could look [like this playground link](//tsplay.dev/WK93KN).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That seems to work perfectly! You rock @jcalz! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a good *specific* type that would meet your needs.  Conceptually `NeedyProcessor` could be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all acceptable input types, like this:

```
type NuttyProfessor =
  { needed: []; process: (needsMet: Pick<Fns, never>) => any; } |
  { needed: ["baz"]; process: (needsMet: Pick<Fns, "baz">) => any; } |
  { needed: ["bar"]; process: (needsMet: Pick<Fns, "bar">) => any; } |
  { needed: ["bar", "baz"]; process: (needsMet: Pick<Fns, "bar" | "baz">) => any; } |
  { needed: ["baz", "bar"]; process: (needsMet: Pick<Fns, "bar" | "baz">) => any; } |
  { needed: ["foo"]; process: (needsMet: Pick<Fns, "foo">) => any; } |
  { needed: ["foo", "baz"]; process: (needsMet: Pick<Fns, "foo" | "baz">) => any; } |
  { needed: ["foo", "bar"]; process: (needsMet: Pick<Fns, "foo" | "bar">) => any; } |
  { needed: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]; process: (needsMet: Pick<Fns, "foo" | "bar" | "baz">) => any; } |
  { needed: ["foo", "baz", "bar"]; process: (needsMet: Pick<Fns, "foo" | "bar" | "baz">) => any; } |
  { needed: ["baz", "foo"]; process: (needsMet: Pick<Fns, "foo" | "baz">) => any; } |
  { needed: ["bar", "foo"]; process: (needsMet: Pick<Fns, "foo" | "bar">) => any; } |
  { needed: ["bar", "foo", "baz"]; process: (needsMet: Pick<Fns, "foo" | "bar" | "baz">) => any; } |
  { needed: ["bar", "baz", "foo"]; process: (needsMet: Pick<Fns, "foo" | "bar" | "baz">) => any; } |
  { needed: ["baz", "foo", "bar"]; process: (needsMet: Pick<Fns, "foo" | "bar" | "baz">) => any; } |
  { needed: ["baz", "bar", "foo"]; process: (needsMet: Pick<Fns, "foo" | "bar" | "baz">) => any; };
```

But that doesn't scale well at all with the size of `fns`, and because it's not a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) it wouldn't even work the way you want... the `process` callback parameter cannot be [contextually typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing):

```
const shouldWorkButDoesNot: NuttyProfessor = {
  needed: ["bar"],
  process: (needsMet) => ({ // error!
    // ---> ~~~~~~~~ implicit any 
    barResult: needsMet.bar(),
  }),
};
```

Oh well.

---

Instead, you should make `NeedyProcessor<K>` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `K` of the elements of `needed`.  And to make it so you don't have to specify `K` manually, you could write a helper function to infer `K` for you.  It could look like this:

```
interface NeedyProcessor<K extends keyof Fns> {
  needed: Array<K>;
  process: (needsMet: Pick<Fns, K>) => any;
}

const needyProcessor = <K extends keyof Fns>(
  np: NeedyProcessor<K>) => np;
```

And now instead of writing `const v: NeedyProcessor = {...}`, you write `const v = needyProcessor({...})`:

```
const working = needyProcessor({
  needed: ["bar"],
  process: (needsMet) => ({
    barResult: needsMet.bar(),
  }),
});
// const working: NeedyProcessor<"bar">
```

And let's make sure it catches mistakes:

```
const broken = needyProcessor({
  needed: ["foo", "baz"],
  process: (needsMet) => ({
    fooResult: needsMet.foo(),
    barResult: needsMet.bar(), // compiler error
    bazResult: needsMet.baz(),
  }),
})
```

Looks good!

---

To get `callProcessor` working, then, you need to make it generic also.  That could look like this:

```
function callProcessor<K extends keyof Fns>(spec: NeedyProcessor<K>) {
  const needsMet = {} as Pick<Fns, K>; // <-- need an assertion here 
  spec.needed.forEach(<P extends K>(x: P) =>
    needsMet[x] = fns[x]
  )
  return spec.process(needsMet);
}
```

Here `needsMet` is of type `Pick<Fns, K>`, the same as the callback parameter type of the `process` method of `NeedyProcessor<K>`.  (In order to get that initialization to compile, I used a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions); after all, `{}` is not a valid value for that type.  `needsMet` only becomes valid after the `forEach()` loop completes).

And let's make sure this also works as desired:

```
console.log("working", callProcessor({
  needed: ["bar"],
  process: (needsMet) => ({
    barResult: needsMet.bar(),
  }),
}));

console.log("broken", callProcessor({
  needed: ["foo", "baz"],
  process: (needsMet) => ({
    fooResult: needsMet.foo(),
    barResult: needsMet.bar(), // compiler error
    bazResult: needsMet.baz(),
  }),
}));
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&noErrorTruncation=true#code/FAjGHsDsGcBcAIBmN4F54G9jyecAueACgEo0A+YjeacAWwFNCAiAEwENZ3mAaXAJxaI8zeAF8SPbPABG7QcTKpKRau0isWHLrwEs5-URKk45AL0KkKVWewvxm7ADa1dAS2gsAFg34MjksBiANzAsACeAA4M8AD6AGIo6BHR4IhIMKFukLC+iOygMYnQ8AwAHrkaJQko1GIgKTEAqpBuUAAq4ACCTk7tAK6RTgzQADztfE1o8O2U6ADaTQC6pRUMVfDzkAwAbr4rAPybK4Ttq5WsJerh8AfSLW2QnT19g8NjAKJloE79rAyjJp8WaUAA+mwm8AAdDCHh1ur0BkMRqMvj8-gCgTNyOQTvBtnt+KFGvAAHL9WARAAK-DSI1o-GmcKeCNeyLGAGsGOE0vBipRyhcStlEL4ZrdxYL1pd4F1+Px2OFRlyeel+bdpNRtgx-poZnxIrTCtBPMRtZcALIMWCEKluUAc0bFYFbfp0GT7chKSjXcTSQgEsUB3a+YlRGLkynhGl0k3gfgAJjQmvxDB1OsI8yWwXghvAxtNRHN0CtNvgdodTpgfED-C91muObE8FBKfNGc2zHMzGzuaN9MsxdLtvtjudDm79eU8Eb4hbbbTuszXfkPZzeYLg8XJetI8r45XhinPsg4Sb85wWsXHfmh90K7Ma77+YHZu3w-Lo6r0D4d5bE7sZhjxnU9z1bS9U3TPVb27X8DCfDdXyLd9d0-fdqwAwx-wfIDvRAs853AzBIKXTthHABD+xNLcdR3MsKzHDDmHI3CG1AwiFyg5cWLgwDe0Q6i31oj8GO-X8WOwyc8NnZsiKvLiyJEXjDH4qjCyHVDRIPCTwTvYCZIvYj22g5ilMw+9u1Ul9BOQ4TNK-bSREk1dnMffT2NkzjSNvHiAMfZTKOs9SUPohymJ08zXNY6cDLkkibxw8SRCszchMtez0J-BwIpw9yCM8iDjOXeCkoolKkI00LMtK0RdPgvKwK8hKSuysycPKmzKr3RistMijnKwurAIajjCuvEyWsS1qyvXNSaPSqqepqgbar86KT3ywz5O8qa+os1cOuCuzFrE6bVr-Ia3OkjytviibAICmrDvmujutOvaVqikaQhAYAIBgBAAHd4w5bIAHNSXAaJCEjalaVFONGXQLAcCKzt4KWExn1S2yFrw1R4AAekJ0p5XjABCaQcGJ+AAFp6fpygAD8WdZln4DcOghntNwEF9QBeDcAIj2qdsfgACURn6Jwy0qqEDFILHjCCUIQGyXJ+HyQoyUXaM1PjUYAGlzmlEoVV5dUUbuwg5QVJUDfIUIcAEo6Fre8d7eus8gjAKA4BI3WgvjaZDeNjYzbVGByCIaRIEiGGdZjAt9Y96xY5V-6-eB-hQcgMHpnNAOk-4VQY-G4qDqx52XtLfHLdMeQJegKWZZCuX5AV6QlYkUIaYzoGQfB+OdUL+l9b0n2AdkWkuUgfOE714vLbRny2ssyu5rSuja5F8jG+b4NjqhciO5wevxcl6WD4Wtvi8kImSYgLm3GGRlfFpfgRfMPfL5Iui27ME+4hAgSGAL3X2CAZDT3WEPVgI9EajA+pdICv1gCIH6JAUAsBHjwFAM4JwidR78BDlKMO3JzaRyINAaIoAYFwIZIbesls+6-1LNMDAzZ2AlC0hhe2OYaajHpiRECM4TS+CwVAeAPg-CyAYLg-o0AYi83gKwcAIxIAAHIEBwHkAgNI6R+BuDBl4WA0gqGyKhMZI+8YPgFC8EQUYVJQ4yntkQMotpvQi0qvMMoKx0DIGgN4pY0gSDSD8LAfo-BZ5mNAFCZ2uMt6hHqH9X24BhhQicOAMGRBmBZxzmDXQuDegEMRiXVGZd0YV2kFXTeNdrClNPgYb+LdD7y0CDgLuJASDpxSWkjJWSuxQMgAUvBxSGT1OXntXij5MZVI3vE2p056k4F3hfZp19j5tIaQ3VZV8-6tL4GAp+L9Sbv0-nYJpuzSz-0AR0rp994ACNpvAWAUiGDqJKJAcAJyg6vOAEAA)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you should use generics instead of an the `needed` property. Something like this:

```
const fns = {
  foo: () => ({ some: "data", for: "foo" }),
  bar: () => ({ and: "data", for: "bar" }),
  baz: () => ({ baz: "also", is: "here" }),
};

interface NeedyProcessor<T extends keyof typeof fns> {
  process: (needsMet: Pick<typeof fns, T>) => unknown;
}

const broken: NeedyProcessor<"foo" | "baz"> = {
  process: (needsMet) => ({
    fooResult: needsMet.foo(),
    barResult: needsMet.bar(), // Runtime error! bar won't exist
    bazResult: needsMet.baz(),
  }),
};
```

I'm sure there is a way to require the needed property to include all values in the union, but I can't come up with it now. Maybe `infer` can be used somehow to make it even easier?

=========

Edit:

I thought about it a bit more and came up with a solution that would keep the array of needed values in runtime.

```
type Needed = "foo" | "bar" | "baz"

const fns = {
  foo: () => ({ some: "data", for: "foo" }),
  bar: () => ({ and: "data", for: "bar" }),
  baz: () => ({ baz: "also", is: "here" }),
};

interface NeedyProcessor<T extends readonly Needed[]> {
  needed: T,
  // Instead of the return type any, 
  // you could use Record<string, ReturnType<typeof fns[T[number]]>> 
  // for the given "broken" example below.
  // Otherwise, I'd recommend using unknown instead of any
  process: (needsMet: Pick<typeof fns, T[number]>) => any; 
}

const broken: NeedyProcessor<["foo", "baz"] > = {
  needed: ["foo", "baz"] ,
  process: (needsMet) => ({
    fooResult: needsMet.foo(),
    barResult: needsMet.bar(), // Runtime error! bar won't exist
    bazResult: needsMet.baz(),
  }),
};
```

The only drawback is that the array of needed has to be sent as a generic type as well as to the `needed` field. If you prefer, you can create an `as const` array and use it in both the generic type and the needed value, like this:

```
const neededBroken = ["foo", "baz"] as const
const broken: NeedyProcessor<typeof neededBroken> = {
  needed: neededBroken,
  process: (needsMet) => ({
    fooResult: needsMet.foo(),
    barResult: needsMet.bar(), // Runtime error! bar won't exist
    bazResult: needsMet.baz(),
  }),
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this will work. It will only be generics that knows about the types, and I need more runtime code to know what fns to inject. Apart from that the other problem you mentioned is interesting to think about, maybe some kind of type mapping? :-)

Comment: @KentLarsson I added another solution which makes it mandatory to add the value so the runtime has access to it.